# Wie schreibt man ‘aw!’ als Ausruf der Verzückung?

Tags: spelling, interjection

Wie würde man auf Deutsch am besten den Ausruf der Verzückung beim Anblick etwas sehr niedlichen wiedergeben, der auf Englisch meistens *aw* oder zur Betonung auch *awww* geschrieben wird?

*Oh* oder *oah* fühlt sich falsch an.

Comment: Ich suche die Beschriftung des entsprechenden Diphthongs, der sich grob als /oa/ notieren lässt.

Comment: Für mich fühlt sich "oooh!" durchaus nicht falsch an. (Der Grad der Verzückung wächst mit der Anzahl der "O"s). Für einen deutschen Muttersprachler liest sich das englische "aww!" übrigens schon irgendwie "eklig", passt also gar nicht.

Comment: Welchen Zweck hat denn das `‘ ’` vor dem letzten Satz?

Comment: @unor Entfernt, war ein Überrest einer Bearbeitung. Btw., in meinem ersten Kommentar sollte es natürlich _**Ver**schriftung_ heißen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [oh](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/oh) , [och](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/och), [ach](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ach), [hach](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hach)

Kann man alles mit *aw* übersetzen

Oh, wie schade - *Aw, too bad.*

(H)ach/och, wie süß - *Aw, how cute.*

Comment: Ein langgezogenes _och_ mit verschlucktem Reibelaut trifft es lautlich schon ganz gut.

Answer (score 5):

Auch hier gilt: Es ist nicht überall im deutschen Sprachraum gleich. In der deutschsprachigen Schweiz wird in diesem Fall immer nur eine einzige Interjektion gebraucht, nämlich:

> Jöö!

Ich weiss nicht, ob diese Interjektion auch in angrenzenden Gebieten in Deutschland und Österreich verwendet wird.

Comment: Für Österreich kann ich sagen, dass »jöö!« sehr weit verbreitet ist.

Answer (score 3):

Relativ verbreitet als Ausruf des Entzückens beim Anblick von etwas Niedlichem – man denke wohl an ein kleines Kätzchen oder Hündchen – dürfte

> Hach!

sein. Das von dir verschmähte

> Oh!

finde ich jedoch auch passend.

> Oh, wie süß!

wird ebenfalls oft zu hören sein. Dann fällt mir noch

> Oj!

ein, dies aber vielleicht eher beim Anblick eines entzückenden Babys.

Die Auswahl eines Ausdrucks mag sehr davon abhängen, was in der jeweiligen direkten Umgebung (Familie, Freunde...) in solchen Fällen üblich ist.

**PS:** Im nachgetragenen Kommentar sagst du dann, dass du nicht einen Ausdruck suchst sondern eine Schreibweise für den Laut /oa/, also etwas zwischen "Oh" und "Ah". Dies würde ich in normaler (druckbarer) Schriftsprache einfach als "Oh" wiedergeben und die genaue phonetische Ausformung der Phantasie des Lesers überlassen.

Comment: Das stimmt, aber derzeit höre ich öfter _*aw, wie süß!_

Comment: Ja, das sagt man so. Die Schreibweise jedoch ist eine angloamerikanische und hat sich in der regulären Schriftsprache (bisher) nicht verbreitet. Im informellen Schriftverkehr (Internet-Geposte etc.) mag es verbreiteter sein. - Eine  traditionelle Methode, phonetische Besonderheiten wie die Nasalität von Vokalen auszudrücken, wo dies denn unbedingt gewünscht ist, wäre es, Diakritika zu verwenden: ôôô! Das wäre für meinen Geschmack besser als der Amerikanismus "aw".

Comment: Ein Problem mit "oh!" sehe ich darin, dass es auch andere Ausrufe, die absolut nichts mit Verzückung zu tun haben (und die tatsächlich "oh" gesprochen werden), repräsentieren kann.

Comment: Das Problem ist klar. Aber was würdest du als Lösung vorschlagen? "Aw" ist ja wohl keine...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Mir begegnet in der Tat am häufigsten "Aw(www...)" und es ist auch die einzige bislang genannte Schreibweise, bei der ich nicht anfange, zu überlegen, was nun eigentlich gemeint ist.